# Unhandled Exception when calling SipProfile.Builder from Android SIP Class

Tags: java, android, object, android-studio, compiler-errors

There is an error when creating a Builder object. This is my code:

```
SipProfile.Builder builder = new SipProfile.Builder("address","username");
```

The error::

> unhandled exception: java.text.ParseException

This is a sample from Android Reference.:

```
public SipProfile mSipProfile = null;
...

SipProfile.Builder builder = new SipProfile.Builder(username, domain);
builder.setPassword(password);
mSipProfile = builder.build();
```

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/sip.html#manager

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, SipProfile.Builder may fail at runtime. It depends on server not the code. Then we should always use it with try-catch block.
This is the working code:

```
try {
    String id = txtId.getText().toString();
    String username = txtUsername.getText().toString();
    SipProfile.Builder builder1 = new SipProfile.Builder(id, username);

}
catch(java.text.ParseException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```